# Google play developer name

Tags: google-play-console

I want to know, if I can in play console, use a company name instead of my real name, because, on the store, it displays my name next to my app, which I don't think looks good. So can I just change it to a company name? for example `X corporation` Is there something i need to keep in mind?

I know it's not a code related question, but I've searched for hours on google, and couldn't find anything useful.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the main page of the console (before you choose your app) and select Developer Page, the top option is Developer Name. I expect changing that will do what you want?

[image: console]

Comment: Yeah, but i want to know, if i'll rename it to something like 'x corporation' would it cause a trouble? because i'm an individual developer, i want to rename so that it looks better and more trust worthy,

Comment: i mean, if am renaming it to something like 'x corporation' do i need to first found a company name 'x corporation' following all the legal things?

Comment: No, I doubt anyone will check

Answer (score 0):

It should not.
I have done recently for changing developer name to my company, then google terminated my account and removed apps from play store.

Comment: How did the situation go on? Account permanently closed? Restored? App removed for ever or readmitted? Let us know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play on **Jan/2022**

You can find out it on the `Developer page`.

[image]